# Yocto Project SDK Plug-in does not install for Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, yocto

On a windows 10 platform, I'm following the instructions for installation of [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#adt-eclipse).

Installation fails with the following error, does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Yocto Project SDK Plug-in 1.4.1.201710162310 (org.yocto.sdk.feature.group 1.4.1.201710162310)
Missing requirement: Utils 1.4.1.201710162310 (org.yocto.remote.utils 1.4.1.201710162310) requires 'package org.eclipse.rse.internal.terminals.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Yocto Project SDK Plug-in 1.4.1.201710162310 (org.yocto.sdk.feature.group 1.4.1.201710162310)
To: org.yocto.remote.utils [1.4.1.201710162310]
```

Comment: Did you try to install the plugin? https://git.eclipse.org/c/tm/org.eclipse.tm.git/tree/rse/plugins/org.eclipse.rse.terminals.ui

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and using "Install New Software...". Not sure what this plugin is called in there.

Comment: This is an Eclipse plugin, it should be cross platform.
I don't use Eclipse, but if you want to use yocto on Windows, please follow this instruction https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#setting-up-to-use-crops . Or use VirtualBox + Ubunt (the easiest way).

Comment: We have a build server with yocto and I'm trying to create an eclipse SDK environment that can remotely access this server from my windows PC. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html says that it should be possible, but following the installation instructions failed to installed the yocto sdk plugin.

Comment: I did try this under VirtualBox and it had the same issue.

Comment: Please add the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/tm/terminal/updates/4.0` in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ and try again (make sure _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ is checked).

Comment: SOLVED - required installation of "Jubula Launch Support for Eclipse RCP" plugin. This solved the missing dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I lost many hours yesterday because of this
As Howard Dowthwaite wrote in a comment:

```
**SOLVED** - required installation of "Jubula Launch Support for Eclipse RCP" plugin. This solved the missing dependency issue – Howard Dowthwaite
```